# How to break text with ellipsis on the second line in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a post title like this:

```css
h2 {
  width: 400px;
  }
```

```html
<h2>How SEO Optimization Helps Your Website to Become on First Page of Search Engine Result</h2>
```

I want to make it appear like this:

```css
    h2 {
      width: 400px;
      }
```

```html
<h2>How SEO Optimization Helps Your Website to Become on First Page of...</h2>
```

How do I do that in JavaScript or even in JQuery?

I want to make my post title get hidden by ellipsis after the second line.

**Thank you!**

Comment: What are you wanting to accomplish? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Do you mean hide text-overflow with an ellipsis? If so, you can do that with css.

Comment: @dwreck08 i want to make the text ellipsis on the second line

Comment: Your snippets do not show a second line.

Comment: @EdBayiates please run the snippet to see how it appear

Comment: So you want to ensure that it wraps to two lines of 400 pixels, but no more than two lines, and truncates any remaining with an ellipsis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With <kbd>[**webkit-line-clamp**](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/)</kbd> and <kbd>[**webkit-box-orient**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-orient)</kbd> like this:

```css
h2 {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  line-height: 21px;
  max-height:45px; 
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2; 
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<h2>How SEO Optimization Helps Your Website to Become on First Page of Search Engine Result</h2>
```

Because firefox not supporting `webkit-line-clamp` (then doesn't show ellipsis), we can do some tricks with `::after` selector *( without `text-overflow: ellipsis;` and `-webkit-line-clamp: 2;` )*, something like this:

<kbd>***For Firefox (also for IE or other browser):***</kbd>

```css
h2 {
  position:relative;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  line-height: 21px;
  max-height:44px; 
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
}

h2::after {
  letter-spacing: .10em;
  content:"...";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  padding:0 10px 2px 45px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="line-clamp">How SEO Optimization Helps Your Website to Become on First Page of Search Engine Result</h2>
```

Comment: @EdBayiates which browser you are using?

Comment: Firefox v 46.  I tried it in Chrome and it did show.  Tried it in IE11 it did not show either.

Comment: maybe it needs `-moz-line-clamp: 2;`  `-moz-box-orient: vertical;` if they are implemented... not sure...  this may help: [CSS line-clamp](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-line-clamp)

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL _-moz-box-orient_ supported in firefox but _-moz-line-clamp_  invalid. then we should find another trick to support firefox.. _Thanks_

Comment: @Shady it shows in Chrome.  It does not show in FF46 or IE11.

Comment: @EdBayiates yes, see my updated answer, i've added some tricks to support other browsers.

Comment: @Shady, very nice, you earned your rep on this one.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a whole lot more efficient than it is, but you can get the general idea.  This method "feels" for the correct height by adding and removing nodes and testing the height of the block.

```js
var headings = document.querySelectorAll('h2');

headings.forEach(function(el){
  var originalNodes = document.createDocumentFragment();
  while (el.firstChild) {
    var words = el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
    words.textContent.match(/\s?\w+\s?/g).forEach(function(word){
      originalNodes.appendChild(document.createTextNode(word));
    });
  }
  el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(String.fromCharCode(8230)));
  
  var currentHeight = el.getBoundingClientRect().height;

  lines = 0;
  while(originalNodes.childNodes.length > 0 && lines < 2) {
    el.insertBefore(originalNodes.removeChild(originalNodes.firstChild), el.lastChild);
    if(el.getBoundingClientRect().height > currentHeight) {
      currentHeight = el.getBoundingClientRect().height;
      lines++;
    }
  }
  if(lines === 2) {
    el.removeChild(el.lastChild.previousSibling);
    el.lastChild.previousSibling.textContent = el.lastChild.previousSibling.textContent.trim();
  } else {
    el.removeChild(el.lastChild);
  }
});
```

```css
h2 {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<h2>How SEO Optimization Helps Your Website to Become on First Page of Search Engine Result</h2>

<h2>How SEO Optimization Helps Your Website to Become on First Page of Search</h2>

<h2>How SEO Optimization Helps Your Website to Become on Testing length</h2>

<h2>How</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the canvas 2D rendering context to measure the text and determine how much text fits on two lines:

```js
var h2 = document.querySelector("h2");
var h2Width = h2.getClientRects()[0].width;
var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "bold 24px Arial";
var words = h2.textContent.split(" ");
var lineWhichFits = [];

var linesUsed = 0;
for(var i = 0;i < words.length;i++){
  lineWhichFits.push(words[i]);
  if(ctx.measureText(lineWhichFits.join(" ")).width > h2Width){
    linesUsed++;
    if(linesUsed == 2){
      words.splice(i);
      h2.textContent = words.join(" ") + "...";
      break;
    }
    lineWhichFits = [lineWhichFits.pop()];
  }
}
```

```css
h2 {
  width: 400px;
  font: bold 24px Arial;
}
```

```html
<h2>A title which has lots of text which means it will stretch over a big area, perfect for this demonstration because obvious reasons</h2>
```

Comment: This will break because it doesn't count the ellipsis.

Comment: It will also break if a word takes up more than a line.

Comment: This will also break if the text breaks (heh) on anything other than a space.